# PHP in Debian Terminal not working with extensions

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, apache-http-server, php

I have Debian 7 installed on my server with a standard LAMP stack and also Mongo DB.

Mongo as well as other third party PHP extensions work correctly through apache.
These extensions however do not work from the terminal.

I've searched to see if others have the same issue however I cannot find an answer. **I'm wandering if perhaps there is a second php.ini file for use by the terminal in Debian?** It seems that the location of the php.ini file varies between linux distro's hence my inability to find info.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they're usually separated. It might depend on the Debian version, but here I've got `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` on `jessie/sid`

Comment: Yes, that worked great. Thanks. For anyone else .... The two files seem to be identical and I was able to simply duplicate my apache version.